# Pass a Ruby on rails variable from .erb file to a php page using a link button

Tags: ruby

I have a .erb file containing a variable - along the lines of:

```
<% my_var = this_var %>
```

Is it possible use something like

```
    uri = URI.parse('http://myOtherPage.php') on this .erb file
```

in order to pass the 'my_var' to 'myOtherPage.php' page when user clicks a link and use it as part of my php script

I basically have a ruby on rails variable that I need to use in a php script, Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Pass it in a query string. `"http://example.com/page.php?my_var=1"`

Comment: Untested but from my understanding you could name the file `filename.php.erb` which will handle the `.erb` portion then the `.php` part. So saying `<?php $php_var = <%= erb_var %> ?>` should work.